# How to improve on a long chain of elseif statements?

Tags: lua

I have have about 100 of these if statements, could I do this a better way?

```
function onSay (cid, words, param)
    mark = string.lower(param)
    if mark == "kojo" then
        moveTo(cid, {x=32838, y=31926, z=7})
        sendEffect({x=32838, y=31926, z=7}, 10)
    elseif mark == "habala" then
        moveTo(cid, {x=32838, y=31926, z=7})
        sendEffect({x=32838, y=31926, z=7}, 10)
    end
    -- and so on.....
end
```

Comment: I fussed with the code formatting... mostly by disposing of the literal tab characters that are possible to paste into the box but not type in the box. I also made the title a little more specific to the question at hand.

Answer (score 9):

Create a table using `mark` as the key, each element of which is a table containing the four parameters (`x`, `y`, `z`, and whatever that last `10` represents).  Then your `onSay` method can be implemented as a table lookup followed by calls to `moveTo` and `sendEffect` using the values from the identified element.  You'll still have to build the table, but you might be able to read it from a file or move it into a separate module so it doesn't dominate your `onSay` method.

Answer (score 1):

LUA lacks a C-style switch, this issue is discussed [here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SwitchStatement), suggesting different methods you could use.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand what you're trying to do, you could try using

```
function onSay (cid, words, param)
mark = param:lower()

if mark:search("kojo", "habala", "and", "so", "goes", "on")  
 then
     moveTo(cid, {x=32838, y=31926, z=7})
     sendEffect({x=32838, y=31926, z=7}, 10)
end
```

of course this unless moveTo and sendEffect will always have the same values